# Non-destructive sort in lisp?

Tags: sorting, lisp

I have been tasked to create a program, and within it I require a function to return a sorted list (in alphabetical order). However, I am unable to use and "non-functional" functions eg "set, setq" etc... And that includes the built in sort function (because it is destructive). So, I was wondering if there is a way to build a non-destructive sort in lisp?

Comment: Is this homework?  Otherwise, that restriction sounds like pure demagogy.  And no, you don't have non-destructive sort in Common Lisp.  Be pragmatic about it, just create a function that copies the sequence, runs `sort` on the copy and returns the result of `sort`.  You can then assume or pretend this new function is non-destructive.  Don't get me wrong, I like purely functional code for as long as it is about as fast as a non-functional approach and it doesn't force me to jump through hoops. If you're urged to jump, you must implement a functional sort yourself.

Comment: I think the typical way in common lisp to do this would simply be to use the destructive sort on a fresh copy of the list. That  satisfies the "functional" api, since callers can'take observe any side effects, and same input in always gets same output back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make a copy before sorting:

```
(sort (copy-seq input) predicate)
```

Or you write a sort function yourself, e.g. quicksort:

```
(defun qsort (input predicate)
  (if input
    (let* ((pivot (first input))
           (rest (rest input))
           (lesser (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x)
                                      (funcall predicate x pivot))
                                  rest))
           (greater (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x)
                                       (not (funcall predicate x pivot)))
                                   rest)))
      (append (qsort lesser predicate)
              (list pivot)
              (qsort greater predicate)))
    nil))
```

[(Demo)](http://ideone.com/kmi7KR)

Note that one could optimize this to detect already sorted rests of a list, enabling structure sharing between the unsorted and sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

If your destructive sort does something like swap two neighboring elements which are surrounded by elements which you leave intact, then a non-destructive way is to create a new list consisting of those two elements swapped, surrounded by the other elements. Then you use that new list as the base for the succeeding sort actions.

Destructively, your working list is the same from start to finish, and you modify it by replacing the value in one "place" by that in another "place". Non-destructively, at each step you create a new list that becomes the working list.

I will leave the implementation to you.